# ¿Porque me Marca Error en las matrices al asignarles valores en C# ?

Tags: c#, .net

Tengo un error en mi código, ya que tengo dos métodos uno que es cargar y otro que es el de faltas, el cargar me indica cuantos empleados son y sus nombres y el de método de faltas me debería de indicar en caso de que hubiera días que haya faltado que dia estuvo ausente el empleado, el problema empieza, cuando yo hago mi ciclo for del método faltas ya que me indica un error.

Este es el error que me marca

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y así es como se queda mi aplicación en consola

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí declaro mis variables

```
private string[][] mat;
    private string[] nombres;
    private string linea;
    private int cantidad;
    private int faltas;
```

De esta forma hago mis dos métodos

```
public void cargar()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el numero de Empleados");
            linea = Console.ReadLine();
            cantidad = int.Parse(linea);
            nombres=new string[cantidad];
            mat=new string[cantidad][];
            for (int x = 0; x < cantidad;x++ )
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el nombre "+(x+1));
                nombres[x]=Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Cuantas Faltas ha tenido " + nombres[x]);
                faltas = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                faltasM(x,faltas);
            }
        }



public void faltasM(int x,int fal)
        {

            for (int c = 0; c < fal; c++)
            {
                Console.Write("Dias que falto:");
                linea = Console.ReadLine();
                mat[x][c] = linea;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que actualmente haces, *en efecto* no es una matriz, se llama ["jagged array"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2576759/what-is-a-jagged-array) y es un arreglo de arreglos que pueden contener distintos tamaños.

Actualmente haces esto:

```
int Matriz[][] = new int[2][]; // Ejemplo
```

Y debes inicializar todos los elementos (2 arrays de 'X' elementos)

```
Matriz[0] = new int[15];
Matriz[1] = new int[1231];
```

Si trabajas con matrices multidimensionales, en C# debes definirlas con la siguiente sintaxis:

```
<tipo>[,] <nombre>;
```

Ejemplo:

```
int Matriz2[2,2];
```

Ahora si tenemos un array multidimensional como la siguiente tabla:

```
+---+---+
| 0 | 0 | <- Matriz[0,0], Matriz[0,1]
+---+---+
| 0 | 0 | <- Matriz[1,0], Matriz[1,1]
+---+---+
```

Puesto que en tu caso, la implementación que buscas, o tiene estilo C, o no aprovecha las caracteristicas de C#.

Entonces, te sugeriria la siguiente implementación (lo he hecho a pura mano, por lo que puede no ser lo que deseas lograr):

Este es el método `Main()`:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ManejoFaltas Manejo = new ManejoFaltas();
    Manejo.CargarDatos();
    Manejo.MostrarDatos();
}
```

He creado una clase para manejar los empleados y la he instanciado en el `Main()`, asimismo, he creado otra clase para mantener los registros de los empleados:

```
public class Empleado
{
    public string Nombre;
    public int Faltas;
    public string[] Dias;
    public Empleado(string nombre, int faltas)
    {
        Nombre = nombre; Faltas = faltas; Dias = new string[faltas];
        for (int i = 0; i < Dias.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("Escriba el día #" + (i + 1) + " que faltó el Empleado: ");
            Dias[i] = Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Y la clase que administra los empleados con todos sus datos:

```
public class ManejoFaltas 
{
    private int CantidadEmpleados = 0;
    private Empleado[] Empleados;
    public void CargarDatos()
    {
        Console.Write("Ingrese el Numero de Empleados: "); 
        CantidadEmpleados = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); 

        Empleados = new Empleado[CantidadEmpleados]; // Definimos el array de empleados.
        string Nombre = "";
        int Faltas = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < Empleados.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("Escriba el Nombre del Empleado #" + (i + 1) + ": ");
            Nombre = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("¿El empleado tuvo faltas? Por favor escribir la cantidad: ");
            Faltas = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Empleados[i] = new Empleado(Nombre, Faltas);
        }
    }
    public void MostrarDatos()
    {
        foreach (Empleado E in Empleados)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("El empleado: " + E.Nombre + " tuvo " + E.Faltas);
            Console.WriteLine((E.Faltas != 0) ? ("Los días: " + string.Join(", ", E.Dias)) : "");
        }
    }
}
```

Talvez sea una implementación muy larga para una tarea tan simple, pero espero que te sirva para tomar algún enfoque, dicho esto, te muestro una prueba en [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qxH7tT), con los siguientes parametros:

```
Número de empleados: 2

Nombre Empleado #1 : Iam
    Faltas del Empleado: 2
    Dias que faltó: Lunes y Miercoles

Nombre Empleado #2 : NaCl
    Faltas del Empleado: 3
    Dias que faltó: Martes, Sábado y Domingo

Nombre Empleado #3 : Jeremy
    Faltas del Empleado: 0
```

Proporciona el siguiente resultado:

```
El empleado: I Am tuvo 2
Los días: Lunes, Miercoles

El empleado: NaCl tuvo 3
Los días: Martes, Jueves, Sabado

El empleado: Jeremy tuvo 0
```

Espero te ayude en algo :)